# How to save and categorize articles I liked?

Tags: google-reader

Currently, if I like the article, I usually mark it "starred" in GoogleReader. Two problems with that:

1. It does not allow to categorize it.
2. Sometimes I find an article not through GoogleReader, so there's no way to "star" it.

Basically, something like InstaPaper, but with categories and search would do the job. Any ideas of webapps available?

Answer (score 3):

If you basically just want to save and categorise them (not a "read later" tool like Instapaper), I'd recommend [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) for the job.

Use tags for categorisation. Delicious is pretty smart in suggesting tags for a page, based on both your tagging history and how others have tagged that page.

Comment: I use Google Reader and Delicious all the time - your answer made me think of something:  Is there a way to automatically save a page to delicious when I star it in Google Reader?  I currently have a big disconnect between the two - I remember reading an interesting article but can't remember if I starred it in Google Reader or saved it with Delicious...

Comment: Good point; I'm not aware of any way to do that. (What I meant above was opening the external link from Reader for any save-worthy article and clicking Tag (provided by Delicious browser extension) to save & tag it. Not as smooth as it could be, agreed.)

Comment: Hmm, if I don't recall wrong, with [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/) app for iPhone/iPad you can directly save Google Reader articles to Delicious. (I'm not 100% sure; have to check.)

Comment: @BrianH I use multiple Greasemonkey scripts to make GReader more user friendly. For your purposes, try this script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/39092 - It adds an "Add to Delicious" button at the bottom of the post. There are several similar scripts out there.

Comment: @BrianH Take a look at http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/08/google-readers-send-to-feature.html It allows you to directly save an item from google reader to delicious.

Comment: Oh nice - Those are all great suggestions!  Thanks so much - I can't wait to try these out!

Comment: @Jonik Yep, Reeder does link to Delicious as well.  I use 2 readers on my iPhone: Byline (primary) and MobileRSS (secondary).  Byline does not support Delicious, but MobileRSS does!  I've linked it already.  I may have to replace Byline with Reeder now.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add the "Note in Reader" bookmarklet to your toolbar from the Notes option (under "Your Stuff" in the left side menu) in Google Reader to add your favorite links.](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-use-google-reader-for.html)